# ASP.NET Core Error Handling with RouteDataRequestCultureProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I used a custom `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider` for localization based on routes. This custom implementation is inspired from [here](https://irensaltali.com/en/asp-net-core-mvc-localization-by-url-routedatarequestcultureprovider/).

And this route used to redirect to default language (As the last route):

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "catchAll",
                template: "{*catchall}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Language", action = "RedirectToDefaultLanguage", culture = "en" }
            );
```

For cookie authentication I used:

```
...
                options.LoginPath = "/login/";
                options.LogoutPath = "/login/logout/"
...
```

For error handling i used this snippet in `startup.cs`:

```
 app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/index/500");
 app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/index/{0}");
```

For example i used this snippet but these does not work either:

```
...
                options.LoginPath = "/{culture}/login/";
                options.LogoutPath = "/{culture}/login/logout/"
...
```

and

```
 app.UseExceptionHandler("/{culture}/error/index/500");
 app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/{culture}/error/index/{0}");
```

Indeed error handling pages and login page not works and always redirects to the default language. What should I do to handle errors and log in with routing localization?

Answer (score 1):

I take and modify code from aspcore github. Change original string "/Error/{0}" to "/{1}/Error/{0}", and add my culture... Put "app.UseStatusCodePages(async context" only after "app.UseRequestLocalization" line.

```
    app.UseRequestLocalization(options);

    app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
    {
        var newPath = new PathString(
                  string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "/{1}/Error/{0}", context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName));
        //var formatedQueryString = queryFormat == null ? null :
        //   string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, queryFormat, context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode);
        //var newQueryString = queryFormat == null ? QueryString.Empty : new QueryString(formatedQueryString);
        var newQueryString = QueryString.Empty;

        var originalPath = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
        var originalQueryString = context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
        // Store the original paths so the app can check it.
        context.HttpContext.Features.Set<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>(new StatusCodeReExecuteFeature()
        {
            OriginalPathBase = context.HttpContext.Request.PathBase.Value,
            OriginalPath = originalPath.Value,
            OriginalQueryString = originalQueryString.HasValue ? originalQueryString.Value : null,
        });

        context.HttpContext.Request.Path = newPath;
        context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString = newQueryString;
        try
        {
            await context.Next(context.HttpContext);
        }
        finally
        {
            context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString = originalQueryString;
            context.HttpContext.Request.Path = originalPath;
            context.HttpContext.Features.Set<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>(null);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Alex! Code-only answers are discouraged here, as they provide no intuition into how the problem was solved. Please update your solution with an explanation of how your code solves the problem at hand